# Can the verb "wish + that clause" express open possibility?

Tags: meaning, tenses, future, wish-preterite

We often use "wish + that clause" to express a past/present counterfactual statement or a future unlikely event (i.e. remote possibility):

> I wish I hadn't quit my job. (But I quit my job.)
>
> I wish I had two million dollars. (But I don't.)
>
> I wish I wouldn't have to work tomorrow. (But I have to. I will be working tomorrow.)

My question is, is it possible to use **wish + that clause** to express open possibilities for the future?

Note: **Open possibility/condition** means the fulfillment of the event is not determined but there is a chance of it happening, as opposed to **remote possibility/condition**, where the speaker knows that the chance of occurrence is remote/unlikely.

For example:

> (?) I wish the weather would be nice this weekend. [future time reference]
>
> *(Intended gloss: I really don't know
> what the weather will be like this weekend, and I haven't checked the
> weather forecast, but I hope it will be nice.)*

I tried to find the answer from the web and in a few grammar books. The only answers I got so far are negative. But the sentence above, about the weather, seems rather natural to me. I even found this example sentence from a grammar book, but the book doesn't say whether it carries the connotation of unlikelihood:

> I wish the weather would get better. I am tired of being inside all
> the time.

To me, that sentence simply expresses the hope that the weather will clear up, i.e. an open possibility.

Comment: I'd phrase "I hope the weather will be nice this weekend" to express what you want to say. However, your sentence have the connotation of unlikelihood, i.e. the current weather isn't that good and you do not really believe in brighter conditions.

Comment: Yes, 'hope' sounds more appropriate than 'wish' in such a statement

Comment: I don’t clearly understand what you mean “open possibilities”. The verb ***wish*** in English does seem to demand a fancier tense/mood/aspect in the second clause than the verb ***hope*** does, something in the irrealis band. “I *wish* the weather *were* nicer. I *wish* you *would stop*.  I *wish* she *were* done.” **vs** “I *hope* the weather *is* nicer. I *hope* the weather *will be* nicer.  I *hope* you *will stop*.  I *hope* she *is* done.”

Comment: I think Cool Elf's answer below is very clear and to the point. However, one of the examples you make is totally wrong in the context you indicate; in fact the sentence ***I wish I hadn't quit my job*** refers to the past (something you did and now regret doing) and consequently it should be removed from your post.

Comment: @Paola The first three examples are meant to illustrate past/present/future. I have edited the wording to make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist "Open possibility/condition" means the fulfillment of the event is not determined but there is a chance of it happening, as opposed to "remote possibility/condition", where the speaker knows that the chance of occurrence is remote/unlikely.

Comment: @langtechie I have no idea what that means.  What's your first language, anyway? All these *would* clauses sound a bit off with *wish*.

Comment: @langtechie ♬ *I wish I were an Oscar-Meyer weiner* ***not*** ♬ *I wish I ∗would be an Oscar-Meyer weiner*.  But *I wish you would be quiet!* is fine.  Hm...

Comment: @tchrist *Open/remote/closed condition (or possibility)* is modern grammar speak. These terms are widely used by recent grammar books in order to distinguish various situations for in-depth analysis. For example, here's a web page that uses the terms with examples: http://members.optusnet.com.au/~furius2006/grammatica/thirdyear/Conditionals-English.html

Could you be more specific about which *wish ... would* sentences sound off to you, and why?

English isn't my native language.

Comment: @tchrist *Would* in "I wish I *would* be an Oscar-Meyer weiner" is odd because *would* refers to future time. But the situation of the sentence is manifestly present: I am not an Oscar-Mayer weiner, but I wish I were one. *Would* would be OK if somehow in reality a person can possibly turn into one in the future. *Would* is natural in "I wish you would be quiet!" because again it has future time reference in what is actually a speech act (a polite request to ask you to be quiet).

Comment: @langtechie If you think there is any difference whatsoever between *were* and *would be* in this case, I think you’ve gotta nother think comin’.  Both are hypotheticals; there is no difference.

Comment: @tchrist I agree that they both are hypotheticals, unlikely to happen. But they must be different in other aspects. Didn't you go with *were* but not *would be* in the weiner sentence? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: It’s because with *to be*, we can inflect it in a unique way that says it’s a hypothetical. With others, we use a modal to convey the same thing.  They are not different in sense, at all.

Answer (score 8):

"*Wish*" is used to express regret and that something isn't as you would like it to be.

> Ex. I wish I knew her number. (= I don't)
>
> Ex. I wish I didn't have to go to school. (= I do)

Even the example that you found in the book:

```
I wish the weather would be nice this weekend.
```

implies that the speaker would like it to be, but the speaker doesn't expect this to happen.

Especially,

```
I wish the weather would get better. I'm tired of being inside all the time.
```

tells us that the speaker wants something to change, but it is unlikely to happen.

---

There is one instance though when the use of "wish" can mean "*open possibility*," to borrow the OP's words.

> *wish + somebody + something*
>
> Ex. I wish you luck.
>
> Ex. I wish you success.

But you cannot wish that something *happens*. You still need to use "hope":

> Ex. I **hope** you **get** a high score.

Comment: On consideration, I think that even the 'wish you luck' is not an open possibility. *I wish you a happy birthday* is not exactly the same meaning as *I hope you have a happy birthday*; it's more of a performative utterance.  But +1 anyway for a clear analysis.

Comment: @CoolElf Thanks for this answer. I have also just read the section on *wish* from *English Grammar in Use* by Murphy. It'll be a book I'll come back to often for basic questions like this.

Comment: No problem. English Grammar in Use is highly recommended

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can use it this way, and I'm not too happy about your examples either.  *Wish*, as I see it used, is never future, always counterfactual; that is, there is always a tacit '...but unfortunately it's not so'.  *I wish I hadn't quit my job* means that you did quit it, and now regret the decision.  *I wish I **didn't** have to work tomorrow* means that you do have to work (and now regret not quitting your job). *I wish the weather would get better* implies that not only has it not done so yet, but there are no signs of improvement, unlike *I hope it clears up* which has no implication either way.

Comment: Thanks. But I do believe that *I wish the whether would get better* does refer to future time, hence the use of *would* (counterpart of "open possibility" *will*). Another way of expressing future remote condition with *wish*: He is going on a trip soon. I wish I *was/were* going too. (But I am not going.)

Answer (score -1):

The word *wish* comes with the heavy baggage of unlikelihood. That said, it seems to me that the OP is restricting any open possibilities in his/her examples through the use of *had* and *would*, two verbs that impart an air of impossibility or uncertainty to the sentence. I think  that a sense of "open possibilities in the future" requires the clear use of *will*:

> I wish that you *will* all do well in your exam tomorrow and make me proud!

Or, with the OP's own example:

> I wish that I *will not* have to work tomorrow.

I expect that one of the grammarians here will be able to better explain the weird past-in-the-future aspect of *would* as a modal auxiliary verb.

Comment: I actually don’t find those examples grammatical.

Comment: @tchrist ... because you would use _hope_ in both of those cases?

Comment: Sorry, the edit doesn't help. *Wish* + *will* is unidiomatic/objectionable, whatever goes with it.

Comment: No, because of what Tim said.

Comment: @coleopterist Thanks for this answer. Indeed, as others have pointed out, *will* (a modal verb usually used for open possibilities) cannot be used in the *wish + that clause* construction, which always expresses unlikelihood.

Comment: @langtechie Why exactly is that? While the sentences don't flow naturally, I attribute that more to lack of use than grammatical incoherence.

Comment: @coleopterist Because of the lack of (enough) evidence supporting *wish + that clause* with normal tense (the kind of tense that *I hope that...* uses) in grammar/usage books, in Google Books and COCA search, from others here, and from the web. That's what my question is about, and I think I got the answer. By the way, I didn't downvote you, in case you wondered.